# Equivalent of Dataframe "diff" with strings

Tags: python, pandas, string

Dataframes in pandas have some functions to perform computation between different rows, like `diff` (https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.diff.html).

However, this only works with numeric computation (or at least objects that supports `-` operation).

Is there a way to perform a different between strings and return a boolean if the strings are equal?

For example:

```
>>> s = pd.Series(list("ABCCDEF"))
>>> s.str_diff()
0    NaN
1    False
2    False
3    True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: `s.ne(s.shift())` and/or `s.eq(s.shift())`.

Comment: @QuangHoang  Amazing! cảm ơn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for Quang Hoang to point out the answer.

You just need to do a new series or Dataframe with a shift of rows and then compare.

```
>>> s = pd.Series(list("ABBCDDEF"))

# If you seach strings that are different
>>> s.ne(s.shift())

# If you seach strings that are equal
>>> s.eq(s.shift())
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
5     True
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Comment: i guess the second one should be `s.ne`?